# How to get tag <h2> in a div class by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags

i wanna get value of h2 in class "myClass"

```
<div class="myClass">
  <h2>some text<h2>
</div>
```

so when in javascript function can write

```
some text
```

may be by document.getElementBy bla bla bla Whatever. i dont have idea about js code.

Any Ideas?

Comment: How do you expect to do work in Javascript if you don't have any idea about it? If you need to get this done, hire someone who knows JS, don't expect free consultation from the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) function to select by CSS selector. Then, use `textContent` to get its (text) value.

```
document.querySelector("div.myClass > h2").textContent;
```

Or, you can get the parent via the `document.getElementsByClassName()` function, and then select its first child (assuming this is the only `class="myClass"` element):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0][0].textContent;
```

Comment: that's what i expected

Comment: What if i change h2 to img src?

Comment: @user3620028 What do you mean "change h2 to img src"? `<h2>` is an element, `src` is an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure on what you are trying to do but you can try this:

document.getElementsByTagName("h2");

Check W3 for example:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp